# What is the correct way to maintain focus on an input in a child component when its parent component re-renders in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component `ChildComponent` containing n number of text inputs. The parent component `ParentComponent` has an `onClick` listener on a `div` that adds a hash to the url:

```
const ParentComponent = () =>
  <div onClick={() => appendHash(#example)}>
    <ChildComponent />
  </div>
```

And the child component:

```
const ChildComponent = () => {
  <div>
   ...
   <input ... />
   ...
  </div>

}
```

What happens is when I initially click to focus in the `input`, it focuses for a split second and then loses focus as the url hash gets added. After the hash is added, the `input` works as expected. `ChildComponent` is being re-rendered when the `onClick` is fired in `ParentComponent` forcing the `input` to lose its focus.

How do I prevent that from happening?

Comment: You can use [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) with child component, that will stop it from re-rendering.